# Create Custom WSO2 ESB Transport

Tags: tcp, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I want to create a new transport processor on WSO2 ESB. This transport is to provide ISO 8583 message processing and transform Raw TCP to SOAP message, vice versa. On the source code, there is a transport management object and inherited by several transport service class such as JMS, HTTP, HTTPS, etc. I have several questions:

1. How the transport management object works?
2. Is that possible to recode TCP service source code and redeploy with my customized actions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 ESB is backed by Apache Synapse and it uses Axis2 Transports to provide the transport layer. You can write a new Axis2 transport and plug it to WSO2 ESB. resources can be found at [here](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/axis2config.html#Receiver) and [here](http://synapse.apache.org/transports.html).

Regards,
/nuwan

Comment: I've configured sender and receiver for my custom transport in axis2.xml. Now the new transport is available in the list of transports when I create a new custom proxy service. But it lacks in the Transport Management console. Should any config except axis2.xml be edited to have a custom transport in this console?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to expose the raw TCP to the ESB, could be to create an ActiveMQ queue to listen the raw TCP and make them available to the ESB.

Answer (score 0):

There are custom transport implementations in the WSO2 ESB which has written for specific customer requirements. FIX (Financial Information Exchange) is such a custom transport. You can get an idea about writing a custom transport if you go through the source code of this transport.

https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/tree/master/modules/transports/optional/fix

Here is a blog post which I have written to explain the process of creating a custom transport for ISO8583 protocol.

http://soatutorials.blogspot.com/2015/06/extending-wso2-esb-with-custom_21.html